# Fetching the text box from docx in docx4j

Tags: java, ms-word, docx4j

Word allows someone to create a text box and fill it with color. I am trying to find out two values from this: 1) the color of the font 2) the color that the text box was filled with

I've tried both examples on docx4j's webapp and below are the differences

1. Text box color = Black. Text color = Black

   ```
   <w:pict>
       <v:shapetype o:spt="202.0" path="m0,0l0,21600,21600,21600,21600,0xe" coordsize="21600,21600" id="_x0000_t202">
           <v:stroke joinstyle="miter"/>
           <v:path gradientshapeok="t" o:connecttype="rect"/>
       </v:shapetype>

       <v:shape o:gfxdata="<bunch of text here>" type="#_x0000_t202" style="position:absolute;margin-left:18pt;margin-top:15.75pt;width:172.65pt;height:1in;z-index:251659264;visibility:visible;mso-wrap-style:none;mso-wrap-distance-left:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-top:0;mso-wrap-distance-right:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-bottom:0;mso-position-horizontal:absolute;mso-position-horizontal-relative:text;mso-position-vertical:absolute;mso-position-vertical-relative:text;v-text-anchor:top" id="Text Box 2" o:spid="_x0000_s1026" stroked="f" fillcolor="black [3213]">
           <v:textbox>
               <w:txbxContent>
                   <w:p w14:paraId="77D94695" w14:textId="70E108CF">
                       <w:r>
                           <w:t xml:space="preserve">This is a simple test by </w:t>
                       </w:r>    

                       <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
                       <w:r>
                           <w:t>foobar</w:t>
                       </w:r>

                       <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
                   </w:p>
               </w:txbxContent>
           </v:textbox>

           <w10:wrap type="square"/>
       </v:shape>
   </w:pict>
   ```
2. Text box color = Black. Text color = white

   ```
   <w:pict>
       <v:shapetype o:spt="202.0" path="m0,0l0,21600,21600,21600,21600,0xe" coordsize="21600,21600" id="_x0000_t202">
           <v:stroke joinstyle="miter"/>
           <v:path gradientshapeok="t" o:connecttype="rect"/>
       </v:shapetype>
       <v:shape o:gfxdata="" type="#_x0000_t202" style="position:absolute;margin-left:18pt;margin-top:15.75pt;width:172.65pt;height:1in;z-index:251659264;visibility:visible;mso-wrap-style:none;mso-wrap-distance-left:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-top:0;mso-wrap-distance-right:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-bottom:0;mso-position-horizontal:absolute;mso-position-horizontal-relative:text;mso-position-vertical:absolute;mso-position-vertical-relative:text;v-text-anchor:top" id="Text Box 2" o:spid="_x0000_s1026" stroked="f" fillcolor="black [3213]">
           <v:textbox>
               <w:txbxContent>
                   <w:p w14:paraId="77D94695" w14:textId="70E108CF">
                       <w:pPr>
                           <w:rPr>
                               <w:color w:val="FFFFFF" w:themeColor="background1"/>
                           </w:rPr>
                       </w:pPr>
                       <w:r>
                           <w:rPr>
                               <w:color w:val="FFFFFF" w:themeColor="background1"/>
                           </w:rPr>
                           <w:t xml:space="preserve">This is a simple test by </w:t>
                       </w:r>
                       <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
                       <w:r>
                           <w:rPr>
                               <w:color w:val="FFFFFF" w:themeColor="background1"/>
                           </w:rPr>
                           <w:t>b</w:t>
                       </w:r>
                       <w:bookmarkStart w:name="_GoBack" w:id="1"/>
                       <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="1"/>
                       <w:r>
                           <w:rPr>
                               <w:color w:val="FFFFFF" w:themeColor="background1"/>
                           </w:rPr>
                           <w:t>foobar</w:t>
                       </w:r>
                       <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
                   </w:p>
               </w:txbxContent>
           </v:textbox>
           <w10:wrap type="square"/>
       </v:shape>
   </w:pict>
   ```

**Question**

How can I access the `w:pict` tag and `v:shape` which is a chid to it. What would be the best way to go about finding these two values in the document?

**What I've tried**

I'm using traversaleUtil like this

```
class DocumentTraverser  extends TraversalUtil.CallbackImpl {
    @Override
    public List<Object> apply(Object o) {
        println " class name"
        println o.getClass()
        if (o instanceof org.docx4j.wml.Text) {
            text.append(((org.docx4j.wml.Text) o).getValue()); //append to text
        }
        else if (o instanceof org.docx4j.vml.CTShape)   {
            org.docx4j.vml.CTShape s = ((org.docx4j.vml.CTShape)o);
            log.debug(s.getFillcolor())
            //how can I get color of the text inside the text box
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the "else if (o instanceof org.docx4j.vml.CTShape)" bit display?  If nothing, are you sure logging is configured appropriately?